# "This row already belongs to this table" even with new row inside loop

Tags: vb.net

I've read previous posts regarding this but there is something else happening that I'm unaware of. All I'm trying to do is insert a new blank row at row 1 and 3. Also I'm pretty sure the row index numbers are wrong since this is going backwards.

```
        Dim dsTemp As System.Data.DataSet
        Dim dtTemp As System.Data.DataTable
        Dim sheet As OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet = Nothing

        dsTemp = CType(Me.uwgGeneratedMatrix.DataSource, System.Data.DataSet)
        dtTemp = dsTemp.Tables(0)
        If dsTemp.Tables(0).Columns.Contains("VerticalID") Then
            dsTemp.Tables(0).Columns.Remove("VerticalID")
        End If

        If dsTemp.Tables(0) IsNot Nothing Then
            For index As Integer = dsTemp.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
                Dim dsRow As System.Data.DataRow = dsTemp.Tables(0).Rows(index)
                Dim value As Object = dsRow.Item(0)
                If Not Microsoft.VisualBasic.IsDBNull(value) AndAlso String.Compare(value.ToString, "ColDes", True) = 0 Then
                    Dim newRow As System.Data.DataRow = dsTemp.Tables(0).NewRow
                    dsTemp.Tables(0).Rows.Remove(dsRow)
                    dsTemp.Tables(0).Rows.InsertAt(dsRow, 0) 
                    dsTemp.Tables(0).NewRow()
                    dsTemp.Tables(0).Rows.InsertAt(dsRow, 2)
                End If
            Next
        End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your code:

```vb
Dim dsRow As System.Data.DataRow = dsTemp.Tables(0).Rows(index)
'...
If Not Microsoft.VisualBasic.IsDBNull(value) AndAlso String.Compare(value.ToString, "ColDes", True) = 0 Then
    Dim newRow As System.Data.DataRow = dsTemp.Tables(0).NewRow
    dsTemp.Tables(0).Rows.Remove(dsRow)
    dsTemp.Tables(0).Rows.InsertAt(dsRow, 1) 
    dsTemp.Tables(0).NewRow()
    dsTemp.Tables(0).Rows.InsertAt(dsRow, 3)
End If
```

What is that code doing? Look at each line and actually ask yourself what it does.

1. First you get an existing row form the table and assign it to the
   `dsRow` variable.
2. Inside the `If` block, you create a new row and assign it the
   `newRow` variable. You never use that variable again, so what was the point of that?
3. You then remove the existing row from the table.
4. You then insert the existing row as the second row in the table.
5. You then create a new row and do nothing with it at all, so what was the point of that?
6. You then try to insert the existing row a second time, as the fourth row in the table.

Is it really unexpected that the error message is telling you that that row already belongs to the table?

For one thing, when you call `NewRow`, that simply creates a new row. That row is NOT added to the table automatically. How could it be? It's empty and the table may have non-nullable columns. You are supposed to populate it as required and then add it yourself.

Apart from that, you can't add or insert the same row twice.

If all you're trying to do is insert blank rows then you need to actually insert blank rows, not existing rows that you removed. You need to twice call `NewRow` followed by `Insert`, e.g.

```vb
myTable.Rows.Insert(myTable.NewRow(), 1)
myTable.Rows.Insert(myTable.NewRow(), 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm dumb, apparently you have to do dsTemp.Tables(0).Rows.InsertAt(newRow, 2)

Comment: Not knowing something is not dumb. Not accepting an answer that explains it to you is dumb.